# Importing a text file of values and converting it to table

Tags: import, string-manipulation, scripting

I just started using Mathematica. I got some output in a txt file from some computations in Pari/GP which looks like this:

$$ [1,2,3,4; 5,6,7,8]$$

Here I want to import the data into Mathematica and get a table. The semicolons indicate a new row and commas separate each entry on a row. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
filename = "C:/data.txt";
First@ReadList[filename, Record, RecordSeparators -> {{"["}, {"]"}}] //
   StringSplit[#, ";"] & // 
 Map[Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number"]]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}

Comment: This works completely fine when the original matrix has dimensions like 3244 $\times$ 7. But for a row vector, as in the text file being [1,2,3,4], your code gives something like {{1,2,3,4}} with an extra brace, this is not interpreted as a matrix in Mathematica.

Comment: @AdityaGhosh `{{1,2,3,4}}` is the Matrix in Mathematica. `{{1, 2, 3, 4}} // MatrixQ` is `True`. By the way,  there not `row vector`  or `column vector`  in vector spaces. `row` or `column` only in `Matrix`.

Comment: Evaluate: `{Dimensions@#, MatrixQ@#} &@{{1, 2, 3, 4}}`. Thanks for the comment by @cvgmt.

Comment: I think using Catenate solves the issue for me, as it removes that extra brace

Answer (score 4):

First we import the data as a string:

```
filename="d:/tmp/test.dat";
tmp=Import[filename][[1, 1]];
```

Then we adjust the syntax:

```
tmp= StringReplace[tmp , {"[" -> "{{", "]" -> "}}", ";" -> "},{"}]
```

Finally we convert the string into an expression and display it:

```
ToExpression[tmp] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. But what's the utility of [[1, 1]] in the second line?

Comment: This gets rid of unwanted braces.

Comment: Actually, without  [[1, 1]], I'm having this issue when I'm using this code on text like [0;1;2;3;4]. As you said, it's giving a lot of unwanted brackets. But including  [[1, 1]] gives the errors:  Part specification is longer than depth of object and String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringReplace. Can you maybe explain how the argument  [[1, 1]] works?

Comment: Check what your file contains. test.dat contains: [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]. The import command should give a string like:  {{"[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]"}} where the double quotes are not displayed by MMA. [[1,1,]] gets ride of the double braces.